# What happens if you try to print with UV resin that's well past it's use by date?

Tags: print-material, resin

I've got a bottle of UV resin that got left at the back of  draw and forgotten about. It's probably 6 months out of its advertized use by date.

What is likely to happen if I try to print with it?

It's Elegoo standard Black.

Comment: Quick answer without research: it may start to self-cure, causing viscosity changes and clumping.  If it is hygroscopic, it may also absorb humidity which can cause it to fail to cure, but a well sealed container should prevent that.  It may be possible to use by filtering for particulates and diluting with fresh resin, but print quality could suffer.

Comment: Try it and find out? Don't use it for anything critical. Expect to have to reprint, be happy if you don't have to.